# write specific value of a row under column at different excel python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe having two columns (Person,counts)
outcome is like-

### Person | Count

A      |2
B      |5
C      |7
D      |9

Now, I want to write the count of each person in an excel sheet having same persons as columns at a particular date
Excel sheet format is like-

### Date |A |B |C |D |E

9/19/2017|

Comment: Can you explain more clearly please?

Comment: thanks for editing it.

Comment: my dataframe has values as table above with columns person and count. I want to write those counts for each person in an excel file in which the person's names are written in columns and the counts for each person is to be written in the row having specific date